# Is PublicKey and PrivateKey in java a Class or an Interface

Tags: java

As i have came to known through https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/security/PublicKey.html that it is an interface.But an Interface cannot create an object but using the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try
    {
    KeyPairGenerator kpr=KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
    SecureRandom sr=SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    ECGenParameterSpec ecgps=new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1");
    kpr.initialize(ecgps,sr);
    KeyPair kp=kpr.generateKeyPair();
    PublicKey p=kp.getPublic();
    System.out.println(p);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

its still working.Can anyone explain this How??I am using Eclipse IDE(openjdk12).

Comment: `getPublic()` obviously returns a class that implements `PublicKey`.

Comment: You can read more about interfaces in the tutorial.  It gives a simple example how to implement an interface. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation has some class that implements the `PublicKey` interface. During the call to `generateKeyPair` the implementing class is created, and is cast to `PublicKey` before it is returned to you. This is a basic "factory design template".

Example:

```
// you see this
interface Foo
{
    void bar();
}

// we hide this somewhere and do not provide the code
class FooImpl
{
    void bar() { ... }
}

// This is the factory that you'll be using
// it will provide you with an instance that implements Foo
class FooGenerator
{
    Foo generate() { return new FooImpl(); }
}
```

Try calling `p.getClass().getName()` and see for yourself!

Answer (score 0):

[`PublicKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/security/PublicKey.html) and [`PrivateKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/security/PrivateKey.html) are interfaces, as you can see from the linked documentation.

> But an Interface cannot create an object...

That's not actually true (default methods can create objects), but that's not what's happening. The object is being created by [`KeyPairGenerator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyPairGenerator.html). The objects in the keypair will be instances of classes that *implement* the `PublicKey` and `PrivateKey` interfaces.

It's exactly like:

```
Map<String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

`Map` is an interface, but `HashMap` is a class; the map assigned to the variable is an instance of `HashMap`. Code in the `KeyPairGenerator` implementation being used will create objects in a similar way, ones that are instances of classes implementing `PublicKey` and `PrivateKey`.